# open source snmp manager library

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I know one can build an snmp client using net snmp. Does anyone know an open source snmp manager library in C? or maybe my understanding is not correct. The net snmp library can also be used to build a snmp manager? I need to build a snmp manager to test my snmp client app.

Thanks.

Comment: An snmp manager is an snmp client that queries MIB objects from another device (that has an snmp agent running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're interested in is testing, I'd suggest simply using some simple command line tools for sending queries to your agent.  The [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) engine you mentioned would work well, and has many online tutorials for how to send queries to your app.  See [the Net-SNMP tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Net-SNMP_Command_Line_Applications) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Wes. I am new to net snmp so I must overlook something here. I was following the instruction here: http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu to install net snmp on my ubuntu. Since I am building snmp directly from the source, I don't know where snmpd.conf is. I think if I can configure snmpd.conf, I can set up the access from localhost. I can only find a snmpd.conf under /var/net-snmp/ which contains warning of do not editing this file. How do I change the access control to allow localhost? I can see snmpd is running.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you're building from source, it's in /usr/local/etc/snmpd.conf but it doesn't exist so you'll need to create it.

Comment: Do *not* edit the one under /var/net-snmp.  See the Net-SNMP documentation for further information on access control and other things.  The tutorials walk you through a lot of it.  Also, run "snmpconf -g basic_setup" to get you started.

Comment: Thanks again Wes, I got it working by using snmpd -c "location of snmpd.conf" command.